# OpenXML save word as txt with encoding of UTF8

Tags: .net, ms-office, office-interop

I want to convert a doc file to txt file, but some characters are lost, see the following code:

```
    object format = WdSaveFormat.wdFormatText;

    doc.SaveAs(ref outputFilePath, ref format,
      ref ObjectConstants.False, ref Unknown,
      ref Unknown, ref Unknown,
      ref Unknown, ref Unknown,
      ref Unknown, ref Unknown,
      ref Unknown, ref Unknown,
      ref Unknown, ref Unknown,
      ref Unknown, ref Unknown);
```

My question is how to set the encoding of txt to UTF8?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check Encoding param in http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.word._document.saveas%28office.11%29.aspx

Comment: Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoEncoding can not be found.

Comment: You need to add the "Microsoft Office XX.0 Object Library". It's in the COM tab when adding references.